# Can't install python-distutils-extra from source in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Linux but I like it more than windows. I'm trying to install [keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx/) to download update packages for my laptop which I've installed Ubuntu on it yesterday. But while install the setup.py. terminal gives an url which it says that I should install it.

But the problem when installing it was:

```
skadush@ubuntu:~/python-distutils-extra-2.35$ python setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
skadush@ubuntu:~/python-distutils-extra-2.35$
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Ubuntu has repos. You don't need to externally update software. Use software updates

Comment: Since you ran `python` (to run the setup.py script), you already have python installed.  I edited the title of your question to reflect this.  I would advise against keryx.  You probably don't need it, and it hasn't been updated in a year and a half.

Answer (score 4):

You should install programs from Ubuntu repositories with Ubuntu Software Centre or apt-get. Ubuntu Software Centre like Android market or Apple app store. It can be found at left in Main menu.
And if you get on well with console, use apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

You should install python-setuptools module. try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-distutils-extra
```

but you were trying install from tarball - the wrong way

Comment: i tried but it says that the follwing application are currently installed

Comment: then you pretty much have python installed, and you can access it by opening a terminal and typing python in it.

Comment: see. I changed my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean python install first remove current python

```
sudo apt-get purge python
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install python-all
```

If this dose not remove python try synaptic package manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Search python in the box and tick/untick any wanted/unwanted packages and click apply

Python 3.0 is recommended as the next Ubuntu release will only support this.

Python 2 should already be installed a good way to test this is open a G-edit and copy this in to the file `print "hello"` then save the file as test.py. open a terminal then drag and drop the file into it and press enter, if the terminal displays Hello python is installed and working.

Answer (score 0):

The message simply indicates that you don't have python-setuptools installed. The python package mentioned comes from that Ubuntu package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

The advice in the other answers to install everything from Ubuntu repositories is wise.